# MySQL 1064 Error when importing a sql file

Tags: mysql, syntax, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to do a really simple thing - import a table into my database.

```
mysql> dbname < libmysql.sql;

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'dbname < 
libmysql.sql' at line 1
```

I don't understand, what is wrong. I even tried to do

`-u username -h host -p dbname < libmysql.sql`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mixing up the `mysql>` prompt and operating system's command line prompt. If you have already connected to MySQL and are at the `mysql>` prompt, [use the `SOURCE` command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-commands.html) to import your file, and be sure you have selected your database with `USE` if you didn't specify it on the command line already...

```
mysql> USE dbname;
mysql> SOURCE libmysql.sql;
```

The `<` for input redirection is used on the operating system's command line, as in:

```
# Example Unix command line...
$ mysql -u username -ppassword dbname < libmysql.sql
```

It's also possible to pipe it in, though you wouldn't want to do this unless the SQL file was being modified by some other process in the pipeline:

```
$ cat libmysql.sql | mysql -u username -ppassword dbname
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have used *PHPMyAdmin* to export the database

- first create the database
- write "USE database_name"
- Import the database